# jquery code working but not the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a small login system using jquery (since it is for testing purposes only and the user and password won't change) So i made a form and when you click the button i test whether the details are correct. if so you will get send to the next page. If not i give an alert.

It's working but i have something weird. The first time you visit the site and fill in the details it does nothing. The second time (after submitting) it works like it should.

Does someone know why?

Here is the code:

```
function  controllogin() {
   event.preventDefault();

   var username = $("#gebruikersnaam").val()    
   var password = $("#wachtwoord").val()    

   if (username=="leerkrachten" && password=="leerkrachten") {
      alert("welkom leerkrachten");
      goToUrl();
   }
   else if (username=="leerling" && password=="leerling") {
      alert("welkom leerling");
   }
   else {
      alert("verkeerde gegevens ingevuld");
   }
};

function goToUrl() {
    alert("zoeken naar pagina");
    window.location = 'leerkrachten/vakken.html';       
};
```

Comment: You cannot make the whole login process client side, by def.

Comment: May I suggest you start with http://jspretty.com? Code (in any language) is easier to read and debug if you use proper indenting and so forth, and since you're asking us to help debug your code the least you could do is make it readable...

Comment: For what you use event.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: Seems to work ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq9L5/)). How are you wiring up the click event of the button to the call to ´controllogin´? Possibly, something is going wrong there (server-side maybe?).

Comment: @Peter I use onClick on the button itself. 

code 

    `<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Aanmelden     onclick="controllogin();" />`

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry will do this in the future

Comment: But if you're preventing the default (ie preventing the submit), why would you use an input of type submit? You could as well just use a button (see my jsFiddle).

Comment: Are you script and html form are in same page...???

Comment: @BwithLove yes they are

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser console??? Is your method controllogin() being called first time you visit the page? Give an alert and check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onclick="controllogin();"` try something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       var username = $("#gebruikersnaam").val()    
       var password = $("#wachtwoord").val()    

       if (username==="leerkrachten" && password==="leerkrachten") {
          alert("welkom leerkrachten");
          goToUrl();
       }
       else if (username==="leerling" && password==="leerling") {
          alert("welkom leerling");
       }
       else {
          alert("verkeerde gegevens ingevuld");
       }
    });
});
```

Also use `===` instead of `==` as operators to compare the strings, it prevents you from some weird results when comparing different types. Maybe that's why it doesn't work the first time, but does the second time. Otherwise I don't know why this happens.

But actually I'd have to say: NEVER do client-side login validation and NEVER do login validation with an unencrypted password (not even server-side)!

Comment: I've updated the code. of course you need to wrap it all in a `$('document').ready()` event listener...

Comment: I already tried that without succes(works in chrome but not in firefox)

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle with the full JS and HTML code?